# replication with SQL AZure from Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to configure replication that can transfer data from SQL Azure DB to AZURE VM with SQL Server?

Basically, i want to move Transactional data from Sql AZURE to local server in Azure VM where SQL Server Standard is installed. I use SSRS From the Server on Azure VM and want to run reports from this data source.

We tried to configure the Geo Replication for SQL Azure DB but unless it is a Premium DB (Which is expensive) we can not decide region for the Secondary database. By default Azure uses North for South region and similar which will make the reports run very slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database replication will not work between two dissimilar SQL Servers. You will need to replicate the data.

There are a couple of options:

1. Periodically run an [SSIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522537.aspx) job on the SQL/VM to regularly pull data from SQL DB into SQL/VM. Ensure the SQL DB firewall is configured properly (refer to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx)).
2. Use [Azure Data Factory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-copy-activity/) to setup a pipeline to periodically move the data from SQL/VM to SQL DB
3. Write a custom data extraction job on the SQL/VM

You can also turn on [Change Tracking on SQL DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) (V12 only) to track the changes that need to be moved between the two systems.